# Tab Layout covering parts of fragment, layout_below not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

So I have a UserAreaActivity that has a layout with tabLayout. Each one of the tabs is its own fragment, however in each fragments layout the tabLayout covers the top of the fragments layout. I have tried using the android:layout_below and giving it the id of the tabLayout but it isnt working properly. Here is my fragments code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
tools:context="com.example.aleksandr.godspeedinvestments.OfferFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="After Repair Value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/afRepValTV" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/afRepValueET"
        android:hint="After Repair Value" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Closing Cost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cc1TV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cc1OutTV" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Agents Fee"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/afTV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/afOutTV" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Repairs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/repTV" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/repET"
        android:hint="Repairs" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/SplitLine_hor1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Net"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/netTV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/netOutTV" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Closing Cost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cc2TV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cc2OutTV" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Holding Cost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/holdCostTV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/holdCostOutTV" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Profit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profitTV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profitOutTV" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/SplitLine_hor2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height= "2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Offer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/offerTV" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/offerOutTV" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my UserAreaActivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_user_area"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.aleksandr.godspeedinvestments.UserAreaActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
    <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabStyle"
        ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: To clarify all of this should be included in the fragments layout [image: This is what should be included in the activity]

[image: However, as you can see the tab layout is blocking the top of the fragment from being displayed]

Comment: Put the `layout_below` attribute on the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Can u share a screen shot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Mike M pointed out, add the attribute "layout_below" in your `ViewPager`. And give an ID to your `AppBarLayout`. Your UserAreaActivity.xml will look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_user_area"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.aleksandr.godspeedinvestments.UserAreaActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >
        <include
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
       />
       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabStyle"
        ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarLayout"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, what you did worked perfectly! You have no idea how many other questions and youtube videos i looked through for an answer and couldnt find it, seriously thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `ViewPager` worked for me.
If it's not in your string file already, the value is `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior`